Is devnet working?
I'm trying to get SOL in devnet. The site says the tokens have been deposited successfully but there is no reflection on the wallet(In testnet mode: solana devnet). Actually, the wallet fails to display any token info.

Which site are you using?
There are many different ways on how to get devnet sol. Here is a guide that shows you 7 different way on how to get devent sol.
https://solana.com/de/developers/guides/getstarted/solana-token-airdrop-and-faucets
For example the web faucet
https://faucet.solana.com/

You might want to check:
https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=devnet
For general status information :
https://status.solana.com/
ALain JS P.
